# Where to get a tutorial on the creation of an mpeg-1 video encoder?

Tags: c++, c, video, encoding

I am looking for educational tutorials (in C or C++) on how to create an MPEG-1 video encoder. So I need all stages - from `char[][] rgb` to some `char [] encodedVideo`. BTW someone told me that it is generally JPEG with a different encoding. Is this true?
Actually there is what I need [ISO/IEC TR 11172-5:1998 Information technology -- Coding of moving pictures and associated audio for digital storage media at up to about 1,5 Mbit/s -- Part 5: Software simulation](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=25029&ICS1=35&ICS2=040) but it is not for free..(

Comment: Normally converting rgb to yuv is not considered part of the video encoder, at least by people who know what they're doing...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [libav library](http://libav.org/) (which is a fork of [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). It has examples, and you can find examples on google, but take a note that it is a complex library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GStreamer library for this. The manual for the C API can be found [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf).

If you want to do everything from scratch then then you'll need to study the MPEG-1 file format specification.